# Error in command - SED (GnuWin) on Windows 10

Tags: sed, command

I'm trying to run a command on Windows 10 (GnuWin for SED) to replace `<link rel="pingback" href="https://example.com/xmlrpc.php">` for nothing, but this command is not working.

```
sed -i "s#^<link rel=\"pingback\" href=\"https://example\.com/xmlrpc\.php\"^>##g" *
```

Where is the mistake?

Thank you!

Comment: what is the error message you get? you are using `#` as delimiter after `s` command, but at the end you are using `+`

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to run this command `sed -i "s#^<link rel=\"pingback\" href=\"https://example\.com/xmlrpc\.php\"^>##g" *`

But after that I don't see any changes. As a result, there is no replacement in the file.

Comment: I don't know about windows quoting (I notice that you are using `^<` and `^>`)... so all I can suggest is first try without `-i` option and start small.. say, try replacing only `pingback` and keep adding text around it until you can spot the issue

Comment: Simple words without special characters are replaced without problems. I cannot figure out my example, which is more complex and contains special characters.